# Why I cannot use the using statement with my static method?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net

**If I use like this in a class It works properly, when I call it from the default.cs:**

```
public class MyMethodsSql
{
    public static SqlDataReader MetodoCommand()
    {            
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Employees";
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        return sdr;            
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = MyMethodsSql.MetodoCommand();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**but when I use the using statement I get an Error: Which says that there is no open connections**

```
 public class MyMethodsSql
 {
     public static SqlDataReader MetodoCommand()
     {            
         string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
         {
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
             cmd.CommandText = "select * from Employees";
             con.Open();
             cmd.Connection = con;
             SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

             return sdr;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: The using statement closes the connection when you exit from the closing brace. When the connection is closed also the SqlDataReader is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLConnection will close/dispose itself before returning the datareader, and the datareader needs an open connection.

Comment: OK, thats mean that instead of the using statement I should use at the end the con.Close(); inside of a try catch and finally, but never with the using?

Comment: @AlexMartinez: Closing the connection has the same effect as disposing it. If you want to return the data reader, then you can't close the connection in the method. To keep the responsibilities reasonable you should either send the connection into the method and return the reader, or do the reading in the method so that you can close the connection and return the data.

Comment: You can still use the using statement, make con a private variable of the class and implement IDisposable on MyMethodsSql, open the sql connection in the constructor and in Dispose() you close the connection, that way the caller can use using on the SqlConnection and MyMethodsSql